# make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am executing a simple makefile that contait 3 parts but it does not work well these are details of my files .h and .c:

1. main.c

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include "hello.h"

   int main (void)
   {
        hello();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
2. hello.h

   ```
   #ifndef hello
       #define hello
       void hello (void);
   #endif
   ```
3. hello.c

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void hello (void)
   {
       printf("Hello World\n");
   }
   ```
4. makefile

   ```
   all: hello
   hello: hello.o main.o
        gcc -o hello hello.o main.o

   hello.o: hello.c
        gcc -o hello.o -c hello.c -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic

   main.o: main.c hello.h
       gcc -o main.o -c main.c -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic

   clean:
        rm -rf *.o

    mrproper: clean
        rm -rf hello
   ```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: if you want to see what your file looks like after the preprocessor runs, try running `gcc -E hello.h`, you'll see that the function name `hello` is gone because you have a `#define` affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hello.h, line 2 you are defining 'hello' as an empty token. Remove that line.

Comment: it went well thank u  but i didn't understand why i had to remove it ? could you explain thar for me please ?

Comment: can't just remove the line. you need to name it something else.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `#define hello` you define `hello` to be an empty token. Thus the function declaration on the next string effectively becomes this:

```
void (void);
```

which is not valid C code.

What you are trying to do is probably the [Include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), its purpose is to avoid multiple inclusion of one header. The name of the guard have to differ from any other token you use. Usual naming is `FILENAME_H`:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
void hello(void);
#endif
```

Comment: There was a typo in the answer saying that the snippet is a valid C code. Of course it is NOT valid, fixed it.